# python multidimensional boolean array?

Tags: python, arrays, boolean

it would contain at most 1000 x 1000 x 1000 elements, which is too big for python dictionary.

with dict, around 30 x 1000 x 1000 elements, on my machine it already consumed 2gb of memory and everything got stoned.

any modules that can handle 3-dimension array whose value would be only True/False? I check bitarray http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray, which seems reasonable and coded in C, however it seems more like a bit-stream instead of an array, since it supports only 1 dimension.

Comment: You could make a `bitarray` and then just do the indexing yourself.

Comment: In many programming contexts, people use "array" when they mean "an array with exactly 1 dimension" rather than in the more general sense. Which is why you often find people doing arrays of arrays (a `list` of `list`s of `bitarray`s) or faking an N-D array in a 1-D array (`a[z*1000*1000+y*1000+x]` instead of `a[x, y, z]`)—because they don't really have a general array type, just a 1-D array type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy` has already been suggested by EnricoGiampieri, and if you can use this, you should.

Otherwise, there are two choices:

A jagged array, as suggested by NPE, would be a `list` of `list` of `bitarray`s. This allows you to have jagged bounds—e.g., each row could be a different width, or even independently resizable:

```
bits3d = [[bitarray.bitarray(1000) for y in range(1000)] for x in range(1000)]
myvalue = bits3d[x][y][z]
```

Alternatively, as suggested by Xymostech, do your own indexing on a 1-D array:

```
bits3d = bitarray.bitarray(1000*1000*1000)
myvalue = bits3d[x + y*1000 + z*1000*1000]
```

Either way, you'd probably want to wrap this up in a class, so you can do this:

```
bits3d = BitArray(1000, 1000, 1000)
myvalue = bits3d[x, y, z]
```

That's as easy as:

```
class Jagged3DBitArray(object):
    def __init__(self, xsize, ysize, zsize):
        self.lll = [[bitarray(zsize) for y in range(ysize)] 
                    for x in range(xsize)]
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        x, y, z = key
        return self.lll[x][y][z]
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        x, y, z = key
        self.lll[x][y][z] = value

class Fixed3DBitArray(object):
    def __init__(self, xsize, ysize, zsize):
        self.xsize, self.ysize, self.zsize = xsize, ysize, zsize
        self.b = bitarray(xsize * ysize * zsize)
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        x, y, z = key
        return self.b[x + y * self.ysize + z * self.ysize * self.zsize]
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        x, y, z = key
        self.b[x + y * self.ysize + z * self.ysize * self.zsize] = value
```

Of course if you want more functionality (like slicing), you have to write a bit more.

The jagged array will use a bit more memory (after all, you have the overhead of 1M `bitarray` objects and 1K `list` objects), and may be a bit slower, but this usually won't make much difference.

The important deciding factor should be whether it's inherently an error for your data to have jagged rows. If so, use the second solution; if it might be useful to have jagged or resizable rows, use the former. (Keeping in mind that I'd use `numpy` over either solution, if at all possible.)

Answer (score 6):

numpy is your friend:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((1000,1000,1000), dtype=bool)
a[1,10,100] = True
```

Has a memory footprint as little as possible.

#### EDIT:

If you really need you can also look at the defaultdict class container in the collections module, which doesn't store the values that are of the default value. But if it's not really a must, use numpy.

Comment: I'm confused by your edit.  What do you mean "doesn't store the values that are of the given value"?  I think you might not understand what a `defaultdict` actually is or does.

Comment: I think the edit means that you can set the default value as either true or false, and then only need to store the locations that are the other.  Basically a sparse array.

Comment: As @tcaswell said, I was referring to the default value set ofr the default dict. Not my best english moment, that's for sure.

Comment: With respect, I think *Has a memory footprint as little as possible* is misleading. AFAIK this takes one byte per bool.

Answer (score 2):

How about a list of lists of bitarrays, perhaps wrapped into your own class with a nice API?

Alternatively, an 3D NumPy array of integers, with your own code packing/unpacking multiple booleans into each integer.

Comment: +1. But you don't need to manually pack things into a numpy array of integers when you can use a numpy array of bools that does that for you.

Comment: @abarnert: Are you sure about that? I thought that NumPy would use one byte -- and not one bit -- per bool. Are you saying that's not the case?

Comment: I haven't tested. I don't think I've ever used `numpy` for `bool` values… but IIRC, long ago with `numeric` you had to use different types for 1-bit bool arrays and 8-bit bool arrays, so you may well be right. (At any rate, even 1-byte values would get down to just over 1GB instead of 6GB…)

Comment: Instead of guessing: `numpy.zeros(1000, 1000, 1000, dtype=bool).dtype` returns `1000000000`, 1GB, so it looks like you're right.

Comment: But it looks like you can use [packbits](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html#numpy.packbits) to pack one of the dimensions into bits. You may have to unpack slices, etc. to actually use the data; I've never used this before. But it'll still probably be easier than doing your own pack/unpack code everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

How about getting inspired by unix file permissions? `755` is read,write,execute for owner and read,execute for everyone else. This is because `7` translates to binary `111`.

So your 1000x1000x1000 bool array could be a 1000x1000 list of `int`s in which the binary representation of each int gives you a 1000 "bit" string representing the bool array.

All of that should fit in under 1GB of memory

Comment: I think a `list` of `list`s of `bitarray`s would be simpler and clearer to read than a `list` of `list` of `int`s.